# MS Access Crashed an now all Form objects and code modules are missing

Tags: ms-access, crash

I was adding a form to our Access 07 db.  I copied an existing form to use as a template, renamed it, and saved it.  I opened a different form to check something and Access crashed.  When I reopened the database it says: "Access has detected that this database is in an inconsistent state, and will attempt to recover the database." etc.

When it reopened - all forms and reports were missing.  Saved queries remain.  The error message states that object recovery failures will be noted in a Recovery Errors table - but this table wasn't created. The links to the be database remained intact.

The database is split - I was experimenting with a form on a front-end copy which might have something to do with it.

Any ideas what would cause this (I can see loosing recent work - but nixing *all* form objects?!)  And is there any chance of recovery?

Comment: Do you take good care of your VBA code in your front end? That is, do you have COMPILE ON DEMAND turned off? Do you use OPTION EXPLICIT? Do you compile regularly and periodically decompile? If you do not do all of these things, corruption can very easily accumulate and then lead to catastrophic loss.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds bad.  Do you have any back-ups, prior versions or shadow copies?  Check the properties of the .MDB through windows Explorer to see if you might have other versions.  Check your system restore to see when the last snap shot was made.  I don't think you will be able to recover from this, but you can probably minimize the damage, and hope for a best case scenario of only losing your most recent changes.

Comment: yeah - have backups - lost only a few hours of work (mostly experimenting with stuff) so not a horrible loss. I'm mostly just amazed that a crash could be so unbeleivably catastrophic.  I haven't encountered a loss of ALL objects before :p

Comment: Yeah, the OLE tree-based single-file Access .MDB file can appear pretty fragile when you start doing heavy-duty database work with it.  Probably the best solution is to eventually upgrade to a non-file-backed database like SQL Server or MySQL, if that is an option for you.

Comment: But it's not a single-file MDB file, but only the front end. All the data, as explained in the question, is in a separate back end database. No data was lost, so upsizing the back end would have absolutely no effect on this user's problem.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't go back up to re-read the problem when I posted the comment.  My bad.